# INDEX - MATCH formula with errors?

Tags: vba, excel, indexing, match

I have the excel formula:

```
=INDEX('C:\Users\Desktop\[BOOK1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$J:$J,MATCH(A2,'C:\Users\Desktop\[BOOK1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$W:$W,0))
```

I am having trouble writing that in Excel vba, this is what I have so far:

```
Dim BOOK1 As Workbook
Dim bcklog1 As Worksheet

Set bcklog1 = BOOK1.Worksheets("backlog1")

Dim result As Variant
Dim match_formula As Variant

match_formula = "Match(Worksheets(1).Range("W:W"), 0)"
result = Evaluate(match_formula)
answer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(2, Worksheets(1).Range("W:W"), 0)
test = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("backlog1").Range("J:J"), result, 1)
index_formula = "Index(sales, result, )"
result2 = Evaluate(index_formula)
```

I am having trouble getting any sort of result, and an error keeps popping up in regards with my match formula. Is my approach even correct? Some results will contain an error, which is expected. The formula should lookup values within another workbook and match them.

Comment: The first thing that strikes me in your code is that you never `Set` BOOK1 to anything.

Comment: Where does the local `A2` come into the formula you are constructing? Why don't you simple `.Evaluate` the string formula you have optionally changing A2 within the string before evaluation?

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: To make the question shorter I omitted the `BOOK1 set as `part.

Comment: @Jeeped: Can you clarify? I can't seem to see where that would go.

Comment: Your original formula incorporates `... MATCH(A2, ...` but the string concatenation uses `= Match(sales & PO, ...`. Which is it? What and where is A2? Are you trying to create new formula with different A2's?

Answer (score 0):

Objective: reproduce a working worksheet formula in VBA

```
=INDEX('C:\Users\Desktop\[BOOK1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$J:$J, MATCH(A2, 'C:\Users\Desktop\[BOOK1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$W:$W,0))
```

Here is a progressive construction using multiple methods. Check the VBE's Immediate window for the `debug.print` output.

```
'assumes that BOOK1 points to a workbook at this point
Dim bcklog1 As Worksheet
Set bcklog1 = BOOK1.Worksheets("backlog1")

Dim result As Variant, test As Variant
Dim frml As String, match_row As Long

'first we construct and evaluate the MATCH portion
frml = "match(A2, " & bcklog1.Range("W:W").Address(external:=True) & ", 0)"
Debug.Print frml
match_row = Evaluate(frml)
Debug.Print match_row

'next we build the remainder of the INDEX/MATCH around the match potion constructed earlier
frml = "index(" & bcklog1.Range("J:J").Address(external:=True) & ", " & frml & ")"
Debug.Print frml
result = Evaluate(frml)

'finally we abandon the Evaluate and use the match_row obtained earlier directly
test = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(bcklog1.Range("J:J"), match_row, 1)
Debug.Print test
```

The external workbook cell range addresses are brought in as strings with the [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) with the optional `external:=True` parameter. This returns a properly formatted string including the full path to the workbook, the worksheet name with single quotes if required and absolute cell range references.

You could write those formula string constructions back to the destination worksheet by prefacing with an equals sign and assigning them to the destination cell's [Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx). The equals sign is not a requirement for the [Application.Evaluate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for that info on referring to outside workbooks!!

Comment: I get an error 13: Type mismatch for `match_row` and ` test` variables. I changed the `match_row as Variant` and that got rid of one error. The `test` variable still returns an error.